# Is there any way to use firefox's cookies with the Apache HttpClient class?

Tags: java, cookies, apache-commons-httpclient

I obviously don't know a ton about cookies, if they'd even be compatible, etc, etc. If this is possible, can someone show an example of how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "use Firefox cookies". Here's a snipet of code that I wrote to grab data from the Goolge Reader API, by passing a cookie along with the Apache HttpClient request.

It needs to send a cookie that Google gives you upon connection ("SID") along with its request. Is this what you are looking for?

```
// Obtain SID
    GetMethod getLogin = new GetMethod("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?service=reader&Email="+
            login+"&Passwd="+password);
    client.executeMethod(getLogin);
    String loginText = getLogin.getResponseBodyAsString();
    // The value of SID is loginText.substring (4,firstLineLength)
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(loginText));
    String SID = loginText.substring(4, reader.readLine().length() );

GetMethod grabData = new GetMethod("http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/broadcast");
grabData.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "SID="+SID);
client.executeMethod(grabData);
```

Comment: hmm, are the cookies simply string data then?

Comment: They are in this particular instance. I'm sending a "get" request to Google with login information, and storing Google's response, which happens to contain my needed cookie, as a substring of the response text. In-terms of getting cookies from your local computer though, I'm afraid I'm not sure :(